# Pull parent projects and Set Page Size Rally API

Tags: rest, api, rally

1.
            I am creating a dashboard for seeing status for all Rally teams. I made an API call which gave me the user stories. But that does not fetch all user stories. So, how to set page size for this url. I tried but it doesn't work.

```
url     = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=((Project.Name%20%3D%20%22" + teamNameEncoded + "%22)%20and%20(Iteration.Name%20%3D%20%22Sprint%20" + key['sprintNumber'] + "%20" + key['sprintEndDate'] + "%22))&fetch=Name,FormattedID,PlanEstimate"
```

How to add a pageSize parameter in this url?

2. How to fetch parent projects from the Rally using the above API call?
   The above API calls fetches only child projects as per the output. But I am not specifying anything to fetch child projects also. So, I need to fetch parent projects also.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you should be able to just add pagesize=2000.  That's the max per request.  If you have more artifacts than that you'll have to make multiple calls to load all the data.

You can just specify `project=/project/12345&projectScopeDown=true&projectScopeUp=true` where 12345 is the objectid of your project.

You won't be able to get what you want using that Project.Name = "" syntax since that will only return results from that one specific project.